# React Native: How to add variables inside View?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the following React Native code:

```
<View>
  {
    a
    ?
    (
      <View/>
    )
    :
    (
      <View/>
    )
  }
</View>
```

I want to create a variable in the first branch of the ternary statement, and thought I could do so like this:

```
<View>
  {
    a
    ?
    {
      let b = 1;
      return <View/>
    }
    :
    (
      <View/>
    )
  }
</View>
```

This gives me the following two Typescript errors, and causes the app to crash: "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects." and "Operator '<' cannot be applied to types '{ return(): any; }' and 'typeof View'"

I have replaced `()` with `{return ...}` in React Native before, and can't understand why it doesn't work here. Any ideas?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

The problem is that where in some areas of Javascript you can use `{return ...}` in place of `()`, ternary operators are not one of them. For example, with an array method like `map()` the following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
array.map(item => {return 1})
array.map(item => (1))
```

but the following two are not (the first is valid, the second throw an error):

```
let a = true ? (1) : (2)
let a = true ? {return 1} : {return 2}
```

The solution for my scenario is to define the variable just outside the JSX. In this case:

```
render() {
    let b = 1
    return (
        <View>
        {
        a
        ?
        (
            <View/>
        )
        :
        (
            <View/>
        )
        }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `return` inside the curly braces. The contents of the curly braces is automatically returned for you.
e.g.

```
{ <mycomp /> }
```

> I want to create a variable in the first branch of the ternary
>   statement

I don't believe you should be creating variables within the return object. Variables should be created in the body of the `render` method. .e.g.

```
render() {
  const myvar = getmyvar()
  return (<someel> {myvar} </someel> )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jsdeveloper. I figured it out and added an edit to my original post. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to do things before returning your view, you could have a function somewhere like:

```
renderMyView(){
    // do what you need here
    // ....
    return <View/>
}
```

and call this function inside your component render

```
render(){
    return (    
        <View>
          {a ? this.renderMyView() : <View/>}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Pergent. I figured it out and added an edit to my original post. Thanks for your input.